# My code doesn't get any errors on building, but won't work

Tags: c++

When I compile the code, I don't get any errors, but the code won't work. I know that because cout at the end of main won't print anything to the console. When I try to debugg, it points to some issues in different header files, like allocator.h, new_allocator.h, stl_vector.h, etc. Nevertheless, If I comment out line 109 (the one that says `ListaEspVazios LEV(Cntr1);`), cout prints the expected result to the console. I must also say I'm new to coding and would appreciate if you could give me some tips as to "bad coding practices" in this code, or suggestions regarding better ways to approach some of the stuff I did here. Thanks in advance!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


typedef vector<double> Dimensoes;
typedef vector<double> Coord3D;
typedef vector<Coord3D> Espaco;


class Caixa {
    int index;
    int qtde;
    Dimensoes DimCx;
    double vol;
    double aBase;
    int aloc;
public:
    Caixa(int idx, int qtde, Dimensoes dim);
    double BuscarIndex();
    double BuscarVol();
};

class Container {
    int _index;
    int _qtde;
    Dimensoes DimCntr;
    double _vol;
public:
    Container(int idx, int qtde, Dimensoes dim);
    Dimensoes BuscarDim();
};

class ListaEspVazios {
    vector<Espaco> ListaEspaco;
public:
    ListaEspVazios(Container cntr);
};

class ListaCaixas {
    vector<Caixa> vCaixas;
public:
    ListaCaixas(vector<Caixa> vCx);
    static bool comparaCaixas(Caixa caixa1, Caixa caixa2);
    vector<Caixa>BuscarLista();
};

Caixa::Caixa(int idx, int qtde, Dimensoes dim)
:index(idx), qtde(qtde), DimCx(dim){
    aloc = 0;
    vol = DimCx[1] * DimCx[2] * DimCx[3];
    aBase = DimCx[1] * DimCx[2];
}

double Caixa::BuscarIndex(){
    return index;
}

double Caixa::BuscarVol(){
    return vol;
}

Dimensoes Container::BuscarDim(){
    return DimCntr;
}

Container::Container(int idx, int qtde, Dimensoes dim)
: _index(idx),_qtde(qtde), DimCntr(dim){
    _vol = DimCntr[1] * DimCntr[2] * DimCntr[3];
}

ListaEspVazios::ListaEspVazios(Container cntr){
    Dimensoes dimInicial = cntr.BuscarDim();
    Coord3D PtA = {0, 0, 0};
    Coord3D PtB = dimInicial;
    Espaco Inicial = {PtA, PtB};
    ListaEspaco[0] = Inicial;
}
bool ListaCaixas::comparaCaixas(Caixa caixa1, Caixa caixa2){
        return (caixa1.BuscarVol() > caixa2.BuscarVol());
}

vector<Caixa> ListaCaixas::BuscarLista(){
    return vCaixas;
}

ListaCaixas::ListaCaixas(vector<Caixa> vCx){
    //Ordenando elementos em ordem decrescente de volume
    vCaixas = vCx;
    sort(vCaixas.begin(), vCaixas.end(), comparaCaixas);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

//Inicialização das caixas
    Caixa cx1(1, 2, {0.253, 0.608, 0.518});
    Caixa cx2(2, 3, {0.263, 0.480, 0.323});
    Caixa cx3(3, 10, {0.203, 0.403, 0.413});
    Caixa cx4(4, 4, {0.170, 0.530, 0.380});
    Caixa cx5(5, 1, {0.285, 0.435, 0.255});


//Inicialização do Container
    Container Cntr1(1, 1, {2.48, 10, 3.28});

//Inicialização da Lista de Espaços Vazios no Container
    ListaEspVazios LEV(Cntr1);


//Inicialização da Lista de Caixas
    vector<Caixa> listaCx = {cx1,cx2,cx3,cx4,cx5};
    ListaCaixas LC(listaCx);
    vector<Caixa> listaOrdenada = LC.BuscarLista();

    cout << "The boxes list, ordered by volume is: \n" << "[";
    for (int i=0; i<5;i++){
        cout << listaOrdenada[i].BuscarIndex() << " ";
    }
    cout << "]\n";
    cout << flush;


return 0;
}
```

Comment: ***When I compile the code, I don't get any errors, but the code won't work*** The compiler is not required to catch logical errors or report about undefined behavior.

Comment: My advice is to use an ide with a debugger like Visual Studio. That way you can step through your code 1 line at at a time looking at your variables and flow after each step.

Comment: ***When I try to debugg, it points to some issues in different header files, like allocator.h, new_allocator.h, stl_vector.h*** Your debugger should have a way to walk the callstack to your code after the debugger breaks. In Visual Studio there is a Stack Frame combo box on the debug toolbar. If you switch this to your code it should at least show you what line of your code was executing when the exception was thrown.

Comment: `ListaEspaco[0] = Inicial;` does the vector have any size at this point?

Comment: I'm using Eclipse IDE. When I run the debugger, it shows the line where I declare and initialize the first `Caixa` object (`Caixa cx1(1, 2, {0.253, 0.608, 0.518});`). It's strange because when I comment out the line (` ListaEspVazios LEV(Cntr1);`), it works just fine. And that line is after that declaration.

Comment: `ListaEspaco[0] = Inicial;` bug  is in the constructor for `ListaEspVazios`

Comment: The problem was solved, but I wanted to thank you for your help, drescherjm! The problem was actually the one you pointed out. Best regards!

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems in your code:

1. The indexes into `std::vector` in several places. For instance:

   ```
   vol = DimCx[1] * DimCx[2] * DimCx[3];
   ```

   In C and C++, arrays and in general classes like `std::vector` start their indexes at 0, not 1.
2. Accessing elements that do not exist yet:

   ```
   ListaEspaco[0] = Inicial;
   ```

   Here you are correctly accessing the first element; however, the `std::vector` is empty.

Both of these issues may crash the program if you are lucky, or simply show bad behavior silently, if you are unlucky.

Answer (score 0):

#### Problem 1 - off by one error

You have an off-by-one error. In your `Caixa` constructor:

```
Caixa::Caixa(int idx, int qtde, Dimensoes dim)
:index(idx), qtde(qtde), DimCx(dim){
    aloc = 0;
    vol = DimCx[1] * DimCx[2] * DimCx[3];
    aBase = DimCx[1] * DimCx[2];
}
```

And in your `Container` constructor:

```
Container::Container(int idx, int qtde, Dimensoes dim)
: _index(idx),_qtde(qtde), DimCntr(dim){
    _vol = DimCntr[1] * DimCntr[2] * DimCntr[3];
}
```

**What's the problem?** When you have a vector or an array of 3 elements, it has elements at index 0, index 1, and index 2:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<double> values { 3.1415, 2.71828, 0.9999 };

    // First value:
    std::cout << values[0] << '\n'; // Prints 3.1415

    // Second value:
    std::cout << values[1] << '\n'; // Prints 2.71828

    // Third value:
    std::cout << values[2] << '\n'; // Prints 0.9999
}
```

When you try to access `DimCx[3]` and `DimCntr[3]`, the code breaks because there's nothing at element 3.

#### Problem 2 - accessing element in empty array

In the below function, you assign `Inicial` to `ListaEspaco[0]`, but `ListaEspaco` doesn't have any elements in in. `ListaEspaco.data()` is null, so this results in a segfault.

```
ListaEspVazios::ListaEspVazios(Container cntr){
    Dimensoes dimInicial = cntr.BuscarDim();
    Coord3D PtA = {0, 0, 0};
    Coord3D PtB = dimInicial;
    Espaco Inicial = {PtA, PtB};
    ListaEspaco[0] = Inicial;
}
```

We can change the code pretty easily by using `push_back` to add it to `ListaEspaco`:

```
ListaEspVazios::ListaEspVazios(Container cntr){
    Dimensoes dimInicial = cntr.BuscarDim();
    Coord3D PtA = {0, 0, 0};
    Coord3D PtB = dimInicial;
    ListaEspaco.push_back({PtA, PtB}); 
}
```

When I run the code now, I get:

```
The boxes list, ordered by volume is: 
[1 2 4 3 5 ]
```

#### Diagnosing code like this in the future

I compiled your code with the Clang compiler's address sanitizer enabled. This compiles it so that there's a stacktrace whenever you get a segfault or make a bad memory access! The compile command is very simple:

```
$  clang++ test.cpp -fsanitize=address
```

Then, when you run the code, it prints out a stack trace of what caused it to break. For example, after fixing the first problem, this is the error it prints:

```
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==6265==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x000000000010 (pc 0x000000504810 bp 0x7ffd73e67170 sp 0x7ffd73e67140 T0)
==6265==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
==6265==Hint: address points to the zero page.
    #0 0x50480f in std::vector<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >, std::allocator<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > > >::capacity() const (/home/me/scratch/a.out+0x50480f)
    #1 0x4fe211 in std::vector<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >, std::allocator<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > > >::operator=(std::vector<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >, std::allocator<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > > > const&) (/home/me/scratch/a.out+0x4fe211)
    #2 0x4fadf7 in ListaEspVazios::ListaEspVazios(Container) (/home/me/scratch/a.out+0x4fadf7)
    #3 0x4fc5dd in main (/home/me/scratch/a.out+0x4fc5dd)
    #4 0x7fe7a66cbb6a in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x26b6a)
    #5 0x41c449 in _start (/home/me/scratch/a.out+0x41c449)

AddressSanitizer can not provide additional info.
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: SEGV (/home/me/scratch/a.out+0x50480f) in std::vector<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >, std::allocator<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > > >::capacity() const
==6265==ABORTING
```

This tells me that somewhere in `ListaEspVazios::ListaEspVazios(Container)` there's a bug that causes the segfault, and the segfault occurs during the construction of a vector. That's what helped me narrow down the error!

Comment: I feel very dumb now. I should have seen that before submitting this question. However, after I fix that, the problem persists.

Comment: Sorry about that. There was a second issue I didn't notice. I added a section addressing it, and now when I run your code I don't get a segfault anymore!

Comment: I also added a section on the tool that helped me find the bug! (I used clang's address sanitizer)

Comment: Sure thing! I'm glad I was able to help!